# "Class-checking" a variable used to set a value inside a property C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Say I have

```
public static class Foo
{
    internal static string Speed;
    internal static string Duration;

    public const string SPEED_0 = "0"; 
    public const string SPEED_1 = "1"; 
    public const string SPEED_2 = "2"; 
    public const string SPEED_3 = "3"; 

    public const string DURATION_0 = "0"; 
    public const string DURATION_1 = "1"; 
    public const string DURATION_2 = "2"; 
    public const string DURATION_3 = "3"; 


}
```

And in another class, made properties public for these variables

```
public static class AnotherClassSomewhere
{
    public static string Speed
    {
        get { return Foo.Speed; }
        set { if( value.??? ) Foo.Speed = value; }
    }

    public static string Duration
    {
        get { return Foo.Duration; }
        set { if ( value.??? ) Foo.Duration = value; }
    }

}
```

How can I ensure that for each property (i.e. `Speed` and `Duration`), they ONLY receive values from either `Foo.SPEED_0/1/2/3` or `Foo.DURATION_0/1/2/3` respectively.

I could just check for a range (e.g. between 0 and 3), given that I know the constant values ahead of time, but I want to force the use of those constants. Is there a way to check if they are from my `Foo` class?

Comment: Why are you using strings to store what is clearly numbers in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you use two enums instead of the constants and make the type of your `Speed` and `Duration` properties `Enum1` and `Enum2`?

Comment: And why the validation takes place in `AnotherClassSomewhere`? make `Speed` and `Duration` properties and not fields of `Foo`, and validate the values there

Comment: @ZoharPeled coz the Serial library requires a string but we have basic enough control that an int is fine for our binary interface

Comment: @41686d6564 I thought this would not work initially, as there are other variables that may not follow the default incremental values of an enum but this might actually work after all.

Comment: @BitShift Enums may have any integral numeric values. They don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: @41686d6564 oh ok is that easily achievable in C#? I couldn't find anything that wasn't a clusterfuck of nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use enum.

```
public static class Foo
{
    internal static string Speed;
    internal static string Duration;
}
public static class AnotherClassSomewhere
{
    public static string Speed
    {
        get { return Foo.Speed; }
        set { if (Enum.TryParse<SPEED>(value, out SPEED result)) Foo.Speed = result.ToString(); }
    }

    public static string Duration
    {
        get { return Foo.Duration; }
        set { if (Enum.TryParse<DURATION>(value, out DURATION result)) Foo.Duration = result.ToString(); }
    }

    private enum SPEED : String
    {
        SPEED_0 = "0",
        SPEED_1 = "1",
        SPEED_2 = "2",
        SPEED_3 = "3"
    }

    private enum DURATION : String
    {
        DURATION_0 = "0",
        DURATION_1 = "1",
        DURATION_2 = "2",
        DURATION_3 = "3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enums and also store them as a string for your Serial library:

```
public static class Foo
 {
    internal static string SpeedString { get; private set; }
    internal static string DurationString { get; private set; }

    private static Speed _speed;
    public static Speed Speed
     {
        get => _speed;
        set
        {
          _speed = value;
          SpeedString = ((int)value).ToString();
        }
     }

   private static Duration _duration;
    public static Duration  Duration 
     {
        get => _duration;
        set
        {
          _duration= value;
          DurationString = ((int)value).ToString();
        }
     }
 }

public enum Speed
 {
 Speed0 = 0,
 Speed1 = 1,
 Speed2 = 2,
 Speed3 = 3
 }

public enum Duration
 {
 Duration0 = 0,
 Duration1 = 1,
 Duration2 = 2,
 Duration3 = 3
 }
```

If your string should also have other values then just numbers, you can also create a dictionary which assings a string to each enum value.